# node js rendered twice

Tags: node.js, express

i am using node js with template enjine ejs, i cant figure why my server is running every request from the browser two times, vecause when i do the same request from postman its only loaded one time, if i see network i get this
[image]

ass u can see the page home is loaded two times, so the req is make 2 times, where the server process times the same request and every thing , but why
after if i look at the request headers made by the browser i see something strange, that the header change its content, in my first(normal)request i get this:
[image]

but in the second request(the one that should'nt be made:
[image]

you can see that the accept parameter is different it looks like if he is requesting for an image in the static files , but i dont know what can be, first i thought was theb server was requesting the favicon.ico file, but its not because i already added a handler for that,

here i gonna let the whole project github code if someone need it and can help:

main files are appjs and server js, and req are handled by the routers folder and routers handle to their controller, is an MVC architecture
https://github.com/jazdevv/social-media-tw

Comment: It is not provides `.env` example , server.js terminated with local mongo. The `app.js` makes warning with `Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'request' of module exports inside circular dependency` message. That project is not reproduce your two times render. BTW it is nice the MongoDB relationship diagram.

Comment: I had the same issue. It's not nodejs, express or ejs issue. You must be using for loop, and most probably using it wrong. That was the issue in my case.

Comment: @jkalandarov loop in ejs or nodejs

Comment: I cannot debug the issue unless I look at the code.